# Probability - binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I started to learn probability, and thinking there's maybe a simpler way to calculate this than I did:

The probability for someone to be sick is 0.4. If I chose 10 people, and X is the number of people that is sick. I need to calculate X≤5.

I thought to do it with the binomial equation: ${\displaystyle P\left(X=k\right)={n \choose k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}}$

To chose zero from 10 and then 1 from 10 etc till I get to 5, and then to sum all the probabilities.

so...is there another way?

Comment: $ P(X\leq 5) = P(X=0) +P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)$ or  $P(X\leq 5) = 1 - P(X=10)-P(X=9)-P(X=8)-P(X=7)-P(X=6)$.

Comment: I think the previous comment agrees with what you said you would do. There might be another way, but I don't think there is a _better_ way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* arrange this calculation in [Horner form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).  There is more overhead, but fewer multiplications and no factorials/binomials.  Let us explain this method with your example.

You evaluated \begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}  \\
& = (1-p)^n  \\
&\quad + \frac{n}{1} \frac{p}{1-p} (1-p)^n  \\
&\quad + \frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n}{1} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^2 (1-p)^n  \\
&\quad + \frac{n-2}{3}\frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n}{1} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^3 (1-p)^n  \\
&\quad + \frac{n-3}{4}\frac{n-2}{3}\frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n}{1} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^4 (1-p)^n  \\
&\quad + \frac{n-4}{5}\frac{n-3}{4}\frac{n-2}{3}\frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n}{1} \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^5 (1-p)^n  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Notice that each term divides all the subsequent terms, so
\begin{align*}
S &= (1-p)^n\left(1 + \phantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right.  \\
  &\quad \frac{n}{1} \frac{p}{p-1} \left(1 + \phantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right. \\
  &\quad\quad \frac{n-1}{2} \frac{p}{p-1} \left(1 + \phantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right. \\
  &\quad\quad\quad \frac{n-2}{3} \frac{p}{p-1} \left(1 + \phantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right. \\
  &\quad\quad\quad\quad \frac{n-3}{4} \frac{p}{p-1} \left(1 + \phantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right. \\
  &\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \left.\left.\left.\left.\left. \frac{n-4}{5} \frac{p}{p-1} \right)\right)\right)\right)\right) \\
\end{align*}
Then, what has this bought us?

```
(* n is a given nonnegative integer  *)
(* p is a given rational or real in [0,1] *)
k := 5  (*  0 <= k <= n  *)
term := (n-(k-1))/k*p/(1-p)
accum := 1
while k >= 0
    accum := 1 + term*accum
    k := k - 1
    term := term * ((n-k+1)*(k+1))/((n-k)*k)
print (1-p)^n * accum
```

The only somewhat awkward expression, `((n-k+1)*(k+1))/((n-k)*k)` is familiar to those old enough to compute these sums mentally or with a non-scientific calculator.  It is easier than it looks.  For instance, when $k =2$, this is "($n$ minus $1$) times $3$; and divide that by (($n$ minus $2$) times $2$)".  (This term, in the nested expression above,  chops off the previous leading fraction and inserts the new leading fraction -- it helps to notice the numerators are increasing, "$n$ minus $1$" bigger than "$n$ minus $2$", and the denominators are decreasing, "times $2$" less than "times $3$".)  It only takes a little practice to do this quickly on a non-scientific calculator.